# $X^4-5X^2+X+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: ring-theory

Could anyone advise me on how to efficiently prove $X^4-5X^2+X+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X] \ ?$

Hints will suffice.

Thank you.

Comment: it's not efficient, but rational root test to show it has no roots then write it as two degree two polynomials and do some horrible calculations to show it is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Check the polynomials of degree 1 and 2 over the field Z[3], if they divide
 the polynomial $x^4+x^2+x+1$. You will find out, that there are none. So,
 the given polynomial must be irreducible over Q.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain the idea behind your suggestion？

Comment: If a polynomial is irreducible over some field Z[p], it is also irreducible over Q.

Comment: I'm not taught this theorem before. Could you please direct me to the relevant links? Thank you.

Comment: The proof is simple, no link needed : Suppose, f(x) = g(x)h(x) with $deg(g)\ge1 , deg(h)\ge1$. Then f '(x) = g '(x)h '(x) , where f '(x) means that f(x) is converted to Z[p] (calculate coefficients mod p). So, if f(x) is reducible over Q, then it is reducible over every Z[p].

Comment: what is $deg(g)ge1 ?$

Comment: I edited my post, sorry. I accidently pressed the enter-key, so the wrong message appeared :)

Comment: the polynomial in question is: $x^4-5x^2+x+1.$ So $x^4-5x^2+x+1 \equiv x^4-2x^2+x+1 $ in $R[X],$ where $R = \mathbb{Z}_3 \ ?$

Comment: You can still add $3x^2$ to get my polynomial.

Comment: Note, that the method only works, if the leading coefficient (in our example : 1) is not divisible by p.

Comment: Noted. I don't quite understand the last sentence of your proof. (I wasn't taught of that before). Could you explain further? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I suppose $p$ must be prime?

Comment: Yes, I know the definition of reducibility

Comment: Yes, if p is not prime, you have no field, but only a ring.

Comment: If a polynomial can be factored in Q, then it can also be factored in any Z[p]. Perhaps, this formulation is clearer.

Comment: If $f(X)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X],$ then $f(X)=g(X)h(X),$ for some non-unit, nonzero$ g(X), h(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X].$ How this imply that $f'(X)=g'(X)h'(X),$ for some non-unit, nonzero $g'(X), h'(X) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[X],$ for every prime integer $p \  ?$

Comment: To calculate f '(x) from f(x), simply calculate the coefficients of f modulo p (which gives a number from 0 to p-1 for each coefficient), the same for g '(x) and h '(x). Since the degree of all polynomials is at least one, neither g '(x) nor h '(x) can be units because units have degree 0 (the only units are the units in the field).

Comment: I see. It is clearer now. Thank you!

Comment: You mentioned that if f(x) = g(x)h(x) with deg(g)≥1,deg(h)≥1. Then f '(x) = g '(x)h '(x) , where f '(x) means that f(x) is converted to Z[p] (calculate coefficients mod p). So, if f(x) is reducible over Q, then it is reducible over every Z[p]. But if the coefficients of $f$ are not integers, how do you express them mod $p \ ?$